# Datatable output not rendering correctly / consistently

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a data table that is filled with data from SQL Database. When I output the value to a console it outputs correctly because it is handling the line breaks `\n`

In the watch window I can see that this is handling everything as it should and its showing me the text like `"\nCreate a balances dataset in order to determine:\r\n\t• Current Balance\r\n\t•`

However when outputting in ASP.Net the watch window value and output shows this `"Create a balances dataset in order to determine:   • Current Balance"`

I am at a loss as to why the two are different and would be grateful if anyone could help me.

I am accessing the data from the data table in a for loop like so

```
var html = new stringbuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      html.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", row[3].ToString()));
}
```

Edit 1

Forgot to mention that when I view the source, the source shows it correctly too

```
Create a balances dataset in order to determine:
• Current Balance
```

Edit 2

I am fully aware that I need to get a 
 tag in, however I need something to latch onto in the string to replace it.

Comment: Simply: line-breaks in html do not indicate new lines or paragraphs. But a **very** important point - your code currently is ripe for an XSS attack. You should **never** write database data directly to an html stream, unless you know it is trusted as valid html (perhaps as pre-rendered output calculated from the actual data). You should *at a minimum* be using an html-encode step. That only fixes the XSS, note - it won't make your line-breaks work in the way you intend.

Comment: This is the data that I am being given to work with, its to build up a web document of technical information that is stored in the database.

Comment: Though you did not show how you are binding the html, but you can try `<%# Eval("MyMultiLineValue").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br />") %>`

Comment: @SivaGopal I shall try this thanks

Comment: "This is the data that I am being given to work with" that doesn't change a thing; you **still** need to html-encode it

Comment: @SivaGopal if you would like to put this as an answer I can accept this...  I didn't consider that it would have been as simple as that... I was expecting the `\n`

Comment: @SimonPrice Provided it as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a binding expression in `.aspx` markup as below:

```
<%# Eval("YourMultilineString").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br/>") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, `<br />` will make a new line when you view the page as rendered HTML, whereas \n will make a new line when you view the source code.

Alternatively, if you're outputting to a console rather than somewhere that will be rendered by a web browser then \n will create a newline in the console output.

So its better to go for `<br/>` if your output is rendered as HTML web page.

Comment: I may not have explained myself well, its not giving me anything to latch on to to replace the \n or \r to replace with a <br /> tag

Comment: html.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", row[3].ToString().Replace("\n","<br/>")));

try this?

Comment: try to replace it in the SQL server query if its not showing it in watch.

Comment: @Simon either the `\n` is there in the source or it isn't. If it is there: replace will work fine. Just because it doesn't show when viewed in the browser doesn't mean it isn't there.

Answer (score -1):

Because `\n` is new line in console mode, but not in html page.
Try replace `\n` to `<br/>`.

Comment: I am aware of that but if you look at the watch window output for the asp.net its not giving me anything to look for to replace

Comment: @Simon `row[3].ToString().Replace("\n","<br/>")` ... ? (I already mentioned the need for html-encode, but here that must come *between* the `ToString()` and the `Replace()`, i.e. `HtmlEncode(row[3].ToString()).Replace(...)`

Comment: my output isn't giving me the `\n` if you look at it